# collectionReference Issue with copying Rest API data to Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-data-factory

When I copy Rest API data to Azure SQL, there is weird issue. If I use ADF V2 Copy Wizard to generate the pipeline, it can insert 3 following records into my Azure SQL DB table.

taskId taskName error error_description
1 abc success success
2 cde success success
3 efg sucess success

If I do any tiny modification like modifying the pipeline description on this pipeline, after that, if I run the updated pipeline, it can only copies following 1 record into the azure sql table.

taskId taskName error error_description
null null success success

note:
Rest API returned data format is as followings:

```
{
    "data": [       
        {
            "taskId": 1,
            "taskName": "abc"
        },
        {
            "taskId": 2,
            "taskName": "efg"
        },
        {
            "taskId": 3,
            "taskName": "ggg"
        }
    ],
    "error": "success",
    "error_Description": "successful"
}
```

The pipeline json code is as followings:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline3",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy_v9u",
                "type": "Copy",
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [
                    {
                        "name": "Source",
                        "value": "api/getTask"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Destination",
                        "value": "[abc].[table1]"
                    }
                ],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "RestSource",
                        "httpRequestTimeout": "00:01:40",
                        "requestInterval": "00.00:00:00.010"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                        "preCopyScript": "truncate table abc.table1"
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "mappings": [
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "taskId"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "taskId",
                                    "type": "Int32"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "taskName"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "taskName",
                                    "type": "String"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$.error"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "error",
                                    "type": "String"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$.error_Description"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "error_Description",
                                    "type": "String"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "SourceDataset_v9u",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "DestinationDataset_v9u",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

On the mapping of the copy activity, I checked the "Collection Reference" since the "data"on json result contains the array data.

I think it is caused by current ADF doesn't save collectionReference on the json file and once I republish it, the collectionReference information is lost somehow. My previous project is working file, I compared the pipeline json file, I found previous one uses "schemaMapping" instead of "mappings" and previous one contains "collectionReference", however current one doesn't contains "collectionReference". Please see following code for 3 months' ago pipeline copying Rest API to sql db:

```
"translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "schemaMapping": {
                            "$.count": "count",
                            "$.next": "next",
                            "$.previous": "previous",
                            "product_id": "product_id",
                            "product_name": "product_name",
                            "city": "city",
                            "country": "country"
                        },
                        "collectionReference": "$.results"
                  }
```

The pipeline should still copy 3 records into the table after I did these tiny modification. In addition, is there any reason the "collectionReference" no longer appears in the json file of the pipeline? How the pipeline knows which node has array collections?

Can you please advise the solution to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue. The 'collectionReference' property indeed got lost after republishing the pipeline. The fix for this issue will be rolled out to product at the end of this week. Please feel free to create pipeline from Copy wizard as a workaround. Thanks.

Also, as you can see, we previously used "schemaMapping" to describe mapping relationship between source and sink. Now it's replaced by "mappings". Both of them are working and it is not the cause of the issue you met.

The useful doc link for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping

Comment: Thanks. I will check it early next week. The pipeline created by Wizard cannot be used in my project since I need to modify the pipeline like adding dynamic parameter. My project has to put it on hold until this is fixed.

Comment: Hi Wang, has the fix rolled into production?